# How to make ValidationError activate in this example

Tags: python, django

I have problem with ValidationError.

### forms.py

```
from django import forms

class life_contract_data(forms.Form):
    age = forms.CharField()
    period = forms.CharField()
    premium = forms.CharField()
    percentage = forms.CharField()
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django import forms

def contract_output(request):
    form = life_contract_data(request.POST)

    age = range(int(request.POST['age']),int(request.POST['age'])+int(request.POST['period']))
    period = range(1,int(request.POST['period'])+1)
    premium_period = range(1, int(request.POST['period']))
    premium = (request.POST['premium'])
    percentage = int(request.POST['percentage'])
    premium1 = []
    premium_total_year = []
    premium1.append(int(premium))
    premium_total_year.append(int(premium1[0])*12)

    for pre in premium_period:
        premium1.append((premium1[pre-1]*percentage)/100 + premium1[pre-1])
        premium_total_year.append(int(premium1[pre])*12 + int(premium_total_year[pre-1]))

    if int(request.POST['age']) >= 65:
        death_capital = 50000000
    else:
        death_capital = 100000000

    if int(request.POST['age']) >= 65 and int(request.POST['period']) > 5:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Age must be lower than 65") #THE CRAZY PROBLEM

    return render(request, 'life/contract_output.html', { 
        'form':form, 
        'age':age,
        'period':period, 
        'premium':premium1, 
        'percentage':percentage,
        'death_capital':death_capital,
        'premium_total_year':premium_total_year,
    })
```

> Added template.html

### template.html

```
<form action="/life/life_contract/contract_output/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="float" id="form_fields">{{field}}{{field.label}}</div><br />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Actually I want if user inputs age>=65 and period>5, he/she faces an error to correct his/her input. But I see this error message from django:

> [u'Age must be lower than 65']

Where is the problem???

Comment: Probably in the template but you haven't shown that

Comment: I've added the template @Sayse

Comment: That template code doesn't show where you are seeing the errors, where do you see that error message?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question. That error is showing up in this template.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]...

Comment: These three files are matched each other and when my `if condition` is true, the Django shows up that above error!

Comment: Ah I figured out the problem, I'll try to write an answer..

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're having is that you're doing the validation in the view rather than letting the form handle it inside the form's `clean` method

```
class life_contract_data(forms.Form):
    age = forms.CharField()
    period = forms.IntegerField()
    premium = forms.CharField()
    percentage = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(life_contract_data, self).clean()

        if cleaned_data.get('age') >= 65 and cleaned_data.get('period') > 5:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Age must be lower than 65")

        return cleaned_data
```

Your view will also need to be changed to called `is_valid` instead

```
def contract_output(request):
    form = life_contract_data(request.POST)

    if not form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'life/contract_output.html', { 'form':form })

    # Do something if it is valid       

<form action="/life/life_contract/contract_output/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

For more information, see [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Comment: Note: I also changed your `period` field to be an integer

Comment: Should `ContactForm` be the same `life_contract_data`?? right? @Sayse

Comment: @MojtabaShoja - Doh! sorry yes, a C+P mistake

Comment: The problem is gone and no error, But showing up a blank white page after submit clicking. @Sayse

Comment: @MojtabaShoja - That would most likely mean you haven't provided a response if the form is valid

Comment: I'll add new views.py in my question, Please check out if any problem is exist! Thanks :)

Comment: Oh @Sayse I found that the `clean` function made my template to show nothing. It means either `if condition` is true or not, nothing shows.